# django startproject using project template gives template TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: django

I am working on a project to customize the `startproject` command to create django projects from project_template, see below:

```
bootstrap/
├── __init__.py
├── conf
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── project_template
│       ├── manage.py
│       ├── project_name
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── apps
│       │   │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   │   └── example
│       │   │       ├── __init__.py
│       │   │       ├── admin.py
│       │   │       ├── models.py
│       │   │       ├── tests.py
│       │   │       ├── urls.py
│       │   │       └── views.py
│       │   ├── contrib
│       │   │   └── __init__.py
│       │   ├── settings
│       │   │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   │   ├── base.py
│       │   │   ├── development.py
│       │   │   └── production.py
│       │   ├── urls.py
│       │   └── wsgi.py
│       ├── requirements
│       │   ├── base.txt
│       │   ├── development.txt
│       │   └── production.txt
│       ├── requirements.txt
│       ├── static
│       │   ├── js
│       │   │   └── base.js
│       │   ├── scss
│       │   │   └── base.scss
│       │   └── vendor
│       │       └── README
│       └── templates
│           ├── 404.html
│           ├── 500.html
│           ├── base.html
│           └── example
│               ├── base.html
│               └── index.html
└── management
    ├── __init__.py
    └── commands
        ├── __init__.py
        └── startproject.py
```

this is the startproject.py

```
import os
import grabone as go
from django.core.management.commands.startproject import Command as StartprojectCommand

EXTENSIONS = ['py', 'txt', 'html', 'scss', 'css', 'js', 'bowerrc', 'rst']


class Command(StartprojectCommand):

    def handle(self, project_name=None, target=None, *args, **options):
        options['extensions'] += EXTENSIONS
        return StartprojectCommand.handle(self, project_name=project_name, target=target, *args, **options)

    def handle_template(self, template, subdir):
        if template is None:
            return os.path.join(go.__path__[0], 'conf', subdir)
        return StartprojectCommand.handle_template(self, template, subdir)
```

When I run `django-admin startproject test1` it creates the project folder etc etc, but it will try to parse the html templates and give me an error:

`django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: 'staticfiles' is not a valid tag library: Template library staticfiles not found, tried django.templatetags.staticfiles`

This is what the template looks like:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
 ...
</html>
```

This is what the INSTALLED_APPS in setting look like:

```
DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'django_extensions',
    'pipeline',
    # Add third party apps here
)

LOCAL_APPS = (
    # Add local apps here
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps
INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
```

Some how the content in the settings is not being executed though...

Comment: Do you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: @alecxe yes, and I wonder why django is trying to parse the templates as I am not running the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed `html` from

```
EXTENSIONS = ['py', 'txt', 'html', 'scss', 'css', 'js', 'bowerrc', 'rst']
```

Worked.